# JQuery AJAX to aspx gives unknown method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using VS2013, the code below gives "unknown method".  I tried to reduce it to the simplest possible test, and I looked at several examples and answers, however, I still can't figure it out.

aspx file, freshly generated, seems wired up properly

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="JQAjaxTest.aspx.vb" Inherits="zz_Work_JQAjaxTest" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div>
             <input type="submit" value="JQAjaxASPXTest" 
                   onclick="JQAjaxASPXTest(); return false;"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span id ="testspan" style="display:none">"Hey, I'm here"</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="JScript.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind, freshly created, breakpoint hits the Page_Load function

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Partial Class zz_Work_JQAjaxTest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    End Sub

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod>
    Public Shared Function JQAJAXTest() As String
        Return "Passed the Test"
    End Function
End Class
```

javascript: seems to fire properly, then gives Unknown Method error on error return

```
function JQAjaxASPXTest() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "JQAjaxTest.aspx/JQAJAXTest",
        data: {},
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (rtnMsg) {
            AJAX_Return_Sucess(rtnMsg)
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            JQAjaxASPXTestError(request);
        }
    })
}
function JQAjaxASPXTestError(request) {
    alert(request.responseText)
}
function AJAX_Return_Sucess(rtnMsg) {
    alert(rtnMsg)
}
```

Comment: try adding '/' before  the url

Comment: @Bharath:  thanks for input. Adding '/' => it can't find the resource, backing up a level it the problem.

Comment: saw that it needed vb.net webmethod attribute and added it, no joy [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Are you missing a space + underscore after `<System.Web.Services.WebMethod>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed :

```
 <WebMethod()> _
```

In vb.net the web method should be called like this :

```
  <WebMethod()> _
 Public Shared Function DisplayData() As String
  Return DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Function
```

The link http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/03/how-to-call-aspnet-page-methods-from.html may help you.